How to use MTKTextureLoader to load png data
I am trying to load some PNG data with MTKTextureLoader newTextureWithData，but the result shows wrong at the alpha area.
Here is the code. I have an image URL, after it downloads successfully, I try to use the data or UIImagePNGRepresentation (image), they all show wrong.
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lxcode.bs2cdn.yy.com/da3d9ae1-93a0-4149-9977-babee7ad2fb8.png"] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    UIImage *tempImg = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    CGImageRef cgRef = tempImg.CGImage;
    
    MTKTextureLoader *loader = [[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device];
    id<MTLTexture> temp1 = [loader newTextureWithData:data options:@{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: @(NO), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureUsage: @(MTLTextureUsageShaderRead), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureCPUCacheMode: @(MTLCPUCacheModeWriteCombined)} error:nil];
    NSData *tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImg);
    id<MTLTexture> temp2 = [loader newTextureWithData:tempData options:@{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: @(NO), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureUsage: @(MTLTextureUsageShaderRead), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureCPUCacheMode: @(MTLCPUCacheModeWriteCombined)} error:nil];
    id<MTLTexture> temp3 = [loader newTextureWithCGImage:cgRef options:@{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: @(NO), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureUsage: @(MTLTextureUsageShaderRead), MTKTextureLoaderOptionTextureCPUCacheMode: @(MTLCPUCacheModeWriteCombined)} error:nil];
}] resume];

Original Image:

Wrong image after using MTKTextureLoader:

